# Bootstrap model won't close because of content, what is wrong?

Tags: bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap (4) modal for Adding Users. The modal will not close properly when pressing the X icon in the upper corner. If I delete all of the content from modal-body then the modal will close properly. If I delete any three of the input fields from the form in the modal-body, then the modal will also close properly. It doesn't matter which input fields I delete, but if I only remove one or two input fields the modal will not close properly, and if I delete three or more or everything it will close properly. I can't imagine that there's a content limit for modals... or that this content would exceed such a limit...

The code is below, I've previously tried wrapping all of the inputs in their own container divs, and wrapping the whole form in a container div and I've tried both of those at the same time. Can anyone identify the problem?

```
<div id="newuserModal" class="modal fade col-lg-6 offset-lg-3">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content" style="background-color:black;border:solid 1px white;">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Add New User</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="color:white;">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="./be/logicadduser.php" method="post">
            <input id="pinnumber" type="number" placeholder="MOKA Login PIN" name="userpin"data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Enter your 4-digit MOKA PIN (EX: 1234)" autofocus required><br>
            <input id="role" type="text" placeholder="Staff Role" name="role" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="EX: RSS, Supervisor, Supports Coordinator" required><br>
            <input id="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="fname" required><br>
            <input id="middleinitial" type="text" placeholder="Middle Initial" name="minitial" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Must be a single letter, no punctuation" required><br>
            <input id="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lname" required><br>
            <input id="phone" type="number" placeholder="Phone #" name="phone" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="EX: 2314567890; Must be exactly 10 digits, numbers only, no spaces" required><br>
            <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Password must be at least 8 characters, with one upper and one lower case letter" required><br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="if(password.type=='text')password.type='password'; else password.type='text';" name="showpass" style="margin-top:10px;">Show Password</button><br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" style="margin-top:10px;">Add New User</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is this located in your HTML document? Previously, in bootstrap v3, it was recommended to place modals as high up in the body as possible. I don't know if this holds true for v4, but it might be worth a shot.

Comment: Yes it's a page just for adding users so this and the button to open it are the only content. I've ditched that modal for now because I can't figure out why it won't work but would still appreciate an answer if anyone figures it out.